# destroy certain activities when network connection unavailable

Tags: android, networking, android-activity

folks,

I would like build an app using android which relies on networking. As we could not know when network connection will be lost, I build an service to monitor the status, and I wanted to kill certain activity when the network is not within access.

Thus, my question is how I can find reference for that activity, I assume it already started, to destory it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `INTENT`, and your activity can use an intent-filter. You would use an "Explicit intent" for this.

This is basically a way to message activities that you want to do something. So you let the activity destroy itself (and maybe alert the user, do some cleanup etc.)

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Comment: hi, thanks for your kind reply. I read the doc following the link, still no clue about how to do it. It seems that the action_* could not be employed, since there are no action related to destory an activity! I tried to use flag, although it just restarted the activity, the code is as following: Intent dialogIntent = new Intent();
     dialogIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.soft", "com.example.soft.test"));
        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent); After testing by turn off the network, it still there

Comment: Don't try to do it at once with the intent. Just send yourself an `INTENT` and write some handle code in the activity. Just test first that you can send an intent that is received by your target activity (s), and then you can simply make a function that calls `finish()` or something else on that intent.

Comment: Thanks, Dude, your suggestion is very brilliant! I would like to try to find the way to work it out, if I make it, I will post it here!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a BaseClass for all your activities and use the [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to listen to network status changes and finish your activity based on the condition.

Also before you do kill the activity do notify the user why the activity was killed.

Comment: I finished the monitoring part, but have no clue how to kill the activity, could I get a reference for the run-time instance of that activity, and then call destory()? I will notify the user the network is not available!

Comment: well just call finish() within the activity.

Comment: Thanks, Ravi, but it is in the servie that detect the lose of connection, how the service code get an reference of run-time activity, which is to be damaged?

Comment: @Nanne is right , you are better off using Intents to listen to a self destruct broadcast :)

Comment: Hi, solved at last, I used a broadcast member to recieve the message from service and when it get, call the following,    Activity t1 = (Activity) context;
  t1.finish(); then it is done! I am also thinking how to use the message and handler to achieve that! Thanks guys for kind suggestions!